# Getting a relation at a previous revision

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Let's say I have two entities as below and I want to keep track of changes.

```
@Audited
public class Table {

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Department department;

    //getters and setter
}

@Audited
public class Department {

    private String name;

    //getter and setter
}
```

After annotating entities by using `@Audited` I have two more dbTables for versioning with table_aud and department_aud.

Let's say I have a table object that points to department with id=1 and name="Department1".
Then I made changes on table name like table1, table2, table3, table4 etc. And I see revisions in table_aud. When I query revisions (specifically latest revision) I get Table object that points to department with id=1 but for the current version of Department.
I mean let's say previous version of Table looks like

```
table.getId() -> 1
table.getName() -> table3
table.getDepartment().getId() -> 2
table.getDepartment().getName() -> Department1
```

Now I change department's name to Department2. And look for the latest revision for Table again and I get

```
table.getId() -> 1
table.getName() -> table3
table.getDepartment().getId() -> 2
table.getDepartment().getName() -> Department2
```

when I query latest revision for Table, Department always points to the current version of Department. However I want it to point to the snapshot or state of the Department before I change it. Is there a way to achieve this with Envers?

Answer (score 0):

If you query for the latest revision, you get the latest data. You'll get the historical data if you query for historical revisions - that's the whole idea of auditing. Revisions capture consistent DB states, each revision corresponding to a commit.

Comment: Yes, that's true. My problem is that when I query the historical data I get it, but except for the relation. Relation is not historical. For the case that I gave the table-department example, when I query historical versions of table entity, I don't get historical versions for the Department. Historical Table entities always point to the current revision of Department entity. That was what I meant.

Comment: Hmm that seems very strange, all the relations should be retrieved at the same revision at which you retrieved the original object. Are you sure you are using the correct revision number, and that the relation is audited?